YOLOv5 ptl model inference results out of bounds of classes array
I have a yolov5 model that I converted into ptl using the code below
import torch
from torch.utils.mobile_optimizer import optimize_for_mobile

torchscript_model = "best.torchscript"
export_model_name = "converted.ptl"

model = torch.jit.load(torchscript_model)
optimized_model = optimize_for_mobile(model)
optimized_model._save_for_lite_interpreter(export_model_name)

print(f"mobile optimized model exported to {export_model_name}")

Now I created a kotlin app that will do the inference. I was able to successfully load the model and infer an image but the results is out of bounds of my class. Below is my kotlin code.
val module = Module.load(assetFilePath(this, "converted.ptl"))
val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(assets.open("1.jpg"))
        val inputTensor = TensorImageUtils.bitmapToFloat32Tensor(
           bitmap,
            TensorImageUtils.TORCHVISION_NORM_MEAN_RGB,
            TensorImageUtils.TORCHVISION_NORM_STD_RGB
        )
val output = module.forward(IValue.from(inputTensor))
val outputTensor = if (output.isTuple) {
    output.toTuple()[0].toTensor()
} else {
    output.toTensor()
}
val scores = outputTensor.dataAsFloatArray
var maxScoreIndex = 0
var maxScore = scores[0]

for (i in 1 until scores.size) {
    if (scores[i] > maxScore) {
        maxScore = scores[i]
        maxScoreIndex = i
    }
}
Log.d("prediction", "Predicted class: $maxScoreIndex")
val className: String = ImageNetClasses.IMAGENET_CLASSES[maxScoreIdx]

class ImageNetClasses {
    companion object {
        val IMAGENET_CLASSES = listOf(
            "100kph Maximum Speed Limit",
            "20T",
            "4.27m-Height-Limit",
            "40kph-Maximum-Speed-Limit",
            "50kph-Maximum-Speed-Limit",
            "60kph-Minimum-Speed-Limit",
            "Approaching-to-Intersection-Merging-Traffic",
            "Divided-Road-Ahead",
            "Give-Way",
            "Half-Y-Junction",
            "Merging-Traffic",
            "No-Overtaking",
            "No-Parking",
            "No-U-Turn",
            "Pass-Either-Side",
            "Road-Narrows-Left",
            "Turn-Right-Ahead",
        )
    }
}

The result says Predicted class: 344938
The error says java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.ImageInferenceActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=17; index=344938
I hope someone can help me properly interpret my result or point out what am I doing wrong.
Thank you.

did you test it in Python before converting? maybe models is wrong? In kotlin you have some Tuple - maybe you get wrong element from Tuple? Maybe first use print() (or whatever is used in Kotlin) ) (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

how many classes do you have? And what value has scores.size? it should have the same value as number of all classes.

I tried printing it that's why I have the condition if it is a tuple or not

frankly, I don't like IMAGENET_CLASSES = listOf(..) which creates 17 classes but original model could be trained on few thousends classes - so it now gives value 344938

maybe you should ask on similar portals DataScience and CrossValidated

Tensor([1, 25200, 22], dtype=torch.float32) this is the result of  Log.d("output", "${output.toTuple()[0].toTensor()}") but my scores.size results to  554400 which puzzles me

did you trained this model or you downloaded it already pretrained?
